# Vim can't correctly define a filetype after removing a swap file

Tags: vim

When I remove a swap file my color scheme doesn't work anymore for this file. Many plugins don't work also.

I suppose that Vim can't correctly define a file type when I remove a swap file.

Comment: Did you try to reload the file? Save the file with `:w`, then reload with `:e`

Comment: Yes, nothing changed.

Comment: How exactly do you remove a swap file and what is the reason to do so? (I will try to reintroduce the situation on my computer) By the way, what kind of operating system (Lin, Mac, BSD, Win) do you use?

Comment: I use Ubuntu. This problem is very old for me and I saw it on many Ubuntu versions. I just do "rm .file.swp".